# In IntelliJ IDEA, how to select next code completion using Tab?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, code-completion

By default we use `⬇️` to select next code completion choice, and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to apply that choice. For example, here if we press <kbd>Down</kbd>, it will highlight `InternalError`; if we press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will apply the `Integer` completion.

[image]

But I'm using Macbook and the <kbd>Down</kbd> key is really small, I want to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select next and simply use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply, just like I do in vim. How to make this setting?

Comment: There is special `Select Next Completion Option` action under "Settings/Preferences | Keymap -->  All Actions | Other" -- this should allow you to have `Tab` instead of `Down`. To have `Enter` to accept the selected entry you need to change the shortcuts for `Choose Lookup Item` and `Choose Lookup Item Replace` actions. By default they have `Enter` and `Tab` as shortcuts (at least here on a Windows keymap). The first inserts the entry as is while the second will replace what you have under the cursor (different usage scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

It might not fit your workflow, but it's a solution I applied.

Under `Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions` you will find keymaps for "Up" and "Down". These can be replaced with whatever you'd like to use instead of arrow keys. I've found that I'm happy with adding command + j/k (or alt + j/k on windows) for down/up to run through the selections.